# Protecting an account after staying logged in in a public place

Tags: account-security

I had forgotten to log out of my personal T-Mobile web account on my computer at work today. When I came home, I remembered, so I logged on to my account at home (different computer, different network, of course, from work), and changed my passwords, pin-codes, as well as security questions. In addition, I have 2FA on.

Is this sufficient? I want to make sure I am logged out of the work location before I go in tomorrow. I want to make sure no one else can make any changes to my online account.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem you will face is based on how the site is designed. If you make all those changes at home, will the site force your work computer to require the user (whoever that is) to log back in before making changes? Good design says that it should, but it depends on that specific site.

1. If T-Mobile forces re-authentication, then you have done what you needed to do.
2. If T-Mobile does not force re-authentication, then someone could sit down at your computer and make their own changes even after all your work.

There is not a lot you can do to protect yourself in the second case. It then becomes a challenging customer support issue.

Comment: That exactly is my question, whether T-mobile has logged me out or not....

Comment: We can't check or test this for you. And even if we determined that it does not, what would your next step be?

Comment: Well I was hoping someone  on here knows about T-Mobile to tell me which scenario 1 or 2 works. If someone else were to make any further changes, I would be notified by text/email, that has not happened. T-Mobile actually communicates any/all changes made to an online account within seconds

Comment: I guess I can't be the only person who has forgotten to log out in this manner....so I was hoping someone else can share their experience

Comment: This is a Q&A site. This is a little different from a discussion site. We cannot, and we would be irresponsible if we did, work from memory on how the T-Mobile site might work. We would need to test to confirm. If this is your question, then you should really be talking to T-Mobile support to ask.

Comment: Just.... change your habits to avoid using computers that you don't own and control fully to login to private sites. In most cases your smartphone (should you have one) is a reasonable alternative for when there isn't anything else available.